# getting code to run on multiple sheets in a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript

I have 4 sheets in my GoogleSheets spreadsheet.
I need the code below to run on every sheet EXCEPT the one called "MRS summary".
I can't seem to get that 'for' loop (the one with the 'g' variable) to work though, because the code only runs for the ACTIVE sheet. But I do know that the Logger.log(g) line is picking up the right indexes...so I think the 'for g' loop is working in the sense that it knows what sheets to look at, but the rest of the code only does what it's supposed to do on the ACTIVE sheet....but I need it to run on every sheet except the one called "MRS summary". Any thoughts?

```
function SearchCols() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                                               
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  skip = ['MRS summary'];
  for (var g = 0, len3 = sheets.length; g < len3; g++)
  {
    var name = sheets[g].getName()
    if (skip.indexOf(name) > -1) continue;
    {
      var expen = ss.getSheetByName("MRS summary")                                                  
      var sheet1 = expen.getRange("A13:A210").getValues();                                          
      var searchCol1 = expen.getRange ('B13:B210').getValues();                                     
      var searchCol2 = expen.getRange ('A13:A210').getValues();                                     
      var searchCol3 = expen.getRange('C13:C210').getValues();                                      
      var searchCol4 = expen.getRange('D13:D210').getValues();                                        
      var searchCol = ss.getRange('A13:A210').getValues();                                         
      var searchVal = ss.getRange('B4').getValue();                                                                                                              

    for (var i = 0, len = searchCol2.length; i < len; i++)                                                           
      for (var j = 0, len2 = searchCol1.length; j < len2; j++)                                      
      {
        if (searchCol2[j][0] == searchVal && searchCol1[j][0] == 
        searchCol[i][0])                   
        { 
          col1[g].getRange(i + 13, 4).setValue(searchCol3[j][0])                                        
          col1[g].getRange(i + 13, 5).setValue(searchCol4[j][0])                                        
        }
      }
    }
    Logger.log(g);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the line "var col1 = ss.getActiveSheet();".
I don't really want it to be the ACTIVE sheet.
I want it to be ALL of the sheets in the spreadsheet except for the 'MRS summary' sheet.

Comment: I've edited the original question to reflect a few changes i made. now the code will grab the correct values for the ACTIVE sheet and paste those values into all sheets except the exluded one (MRS summary)...so it's getting closer. i think there's a problem referencing or looping through the indexes somewhere